# Bash - greater and lower within certain parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm working on a simple random number guessing game, and I've gotten a bit stuck. The core game is working but I want to a bit more to it. Such as, if you are within 10 away (higher or lower) from the random number you get a different message displayed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

name=Jack

num=$(( 1+$RANDOM%101 ))
echo $num

target=$num
goes=0

until [[ $guess -eq $target ]]
do
    goes=$(( $goes+1 ))
    echo "Guess $goes. Enter a number between 0 and 100"
    read guess


    if [[ $((number - $guess)) -gt 10 ]] 
    then
        echo "Too low"

    elif [[ $((guess - $number)) -gt 10 ]]
    then
        echo "Too high"


    elif [[ $(($number - $guess)) -le 10 ]] 
    then 
        echo "You are within ten"

    elif [[ $(($guess - $low)) -le 10 ]] || 
    then
        echo "You are within ten"

    fi
done

echo "Well done $name, it took $goes goes to guess $num"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix.SE. Please don't post a screenshot of text here. Post the text instead. The Markdown editor has all the facilities needed to accommodate fixed-width text. Also see [the editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: What have you tried?  What behavior did you see when you tried it?

Comment: Add your edits with code blocks and not image files. All you need to do is change the last two echo statements to say `You are within ten but too low.` and `You are within ten but too high.`

Comment: Sorry about the images, new to this. So with the code that you have show in my question, it still outputs only the "within 10 but too low" never the higher bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math is the solution :) .. pls check the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=Jack

number=$(( 1+$RANDOM%101 ))
echo $number

target=$number
goes=0

until [[ $guess -eq $target ]]
do
    goes=$(( $goes+1 ))
    echo "Guess $goes. Enter a number between 0 and 100"
    read guess

    if [[ $((number - guess)) -eq 0 ]]; then break; fi

    if [[ $((number - guess)) -gt 10 ]] 
    then
        echo "Too low"

    elif [[ $((guess - number)) -gt 10 ]]
    then
        echo "Too high"


    elif [[ $((number - guess)) -le 10 ]] 
    then 
    if [[ $((number - guess)) -lt 0 ]]
    then
            echo "You are within ten on the higher side"
    else

            echo "You are within ten on the lower side"
    fi
    fi
done
echo "Well done $name, it took $goes goes to guess $number"
```

Comment: Absolute legend! Thanks dude :)

Comment: @JackDent if you decide this is the answer that helped you best, please accept it with the tick mark upper left next to the voting buttons. (But remember this is a 24-hour world and some people could who provide an even better answer might be asleep.)

Comment: The first `if .. then` statement isn't needed because the loop is only run if `$guess` isn't equal to `$target`. If it is, then it won't run the loop anyway and will print the last `echo` string at the bottom. You also don't need a nested `if .. then` statement at the bottom. Two `elifs` for the number being within ten on the higher or lower side will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Change your first statements and add the last part as your `elif` statement:

```
if [[ $((number - $guess)) -gt 10 ]] 
then
    echo "Too low"

elif [[ $((guess - $number)) -gt 10 ]]
then
    echo "Too high"


elif [[ $(($number - $guess)) -le 10 ]] 
then 
    echo "You are within ten but too low"

elif [[ $(($guess - $number)) -le 10 ]]
then
    echo "You are within ten but too high"
fi
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I should have probably explained a little better. The "You are within ten" needs to be if the random number given is 50 and I guess 40 it would output "You are within ten but too low" and lets say I guessed 60 it would output "You are within ten but too high" Does this make sense?

Comment: @JackDent You can figure that out from what's been given in my answer. You only need to break up the last `elif` statement into two separate `elif` statements and add `echo You are within ten but too low` and `echo You withing ten but too high`.

Comment: I did try that but doesnt seem to be working... always outputs too low

Comment: @JackDent Edit your question and add what you tried and where it's not working including any error messages.

Comment: see edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

number=$(( 1 + (RANDOM%100) ))    # random number [1,100]

while read -p 'Guess: '; do
        [[ $REPLY == *[![:digit:]]* ]] && continue

        if [[ REPLY -eq number ]]; then
                echo Correct
                break
        elif [[ REPLY -gt number ]]; then
                too=large
                delta=$(( REPLY - number ))
        else
                too=small
                delta=$(( number - REPLY ))
        fi

        if [[ delta -le 10 ]]; then
                close=' (but close)'
        else
                close=
        fi

        printf 'No, too %s%s\n' "$too" "$close"
done
```

Implements simple input validation (ignores input that contains non-digits), calculates whether the given guess is too large or too small, and also the difference between the guess and the correct answer as `delta`. Using the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), sets variables `too` and `close` to the appropriate strings depending on whether the guess is too large or small and the magnitude of the error, and finally prints a message before letting the user try again.

The game is terminated by a correct guess, or by the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to signal the end of input, or <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to simply interrupt the script.

---

A script that plays the above game.  The script assumes that the above script is available as `guessinggame` in the current directory.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

coproc bash guessinggame

make_guess () {
        printf 'Guessing %d\n' "$1"
        printf '%s\n' "$1" >&${COPROC[1]}
}

guess=50        # initial guess
change=25       # next guess this much higher/lower

make_guess "$guess"
tries=1

while read; do
        printf 'Game says "%s"\n' "$REPLY"

        if [[ $REPLY == 'Correct' ]]; then
                break
        fi

        if [[ $REPLY == *close* ]] && [[ change -gt 10 ]]; then
                # Close call, do not change too much in next guess!
                change=10
        fi

        if [[ $REPLY == *small* ]]; then
                guess=$(( guess + change ))
        else
                guess=$(( guess - change ))
        fi

        change=$(( change / 2 ))
        [[ change -eq 0 ]] && change=1

        make_guess "$guess"
        tries=$(( tries + 1 ))
done <&${COPROC[0]}

printf 'Guessed correctly after %d tries\n' "$tries"
```

Example run:

```
$ bash guesser
Guessing 50
Game says "No, too large"
Guessing 25
Game says "No, too large (but close)"
Guessing 15
Game says "No, too small (but close)"
Guessing 20
Game says "No, too small (but close)"
Guessing 22
Game says "Correct"
Guessed correctly after 5 tries
```